# What is the grammar rule for this OCaml code?

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I'm not familiar with OCaml, but recently have been analysing the syntax of OCaml. I came across this include construct which I can't see which grammar rule it relates to:

```
include Warning(Loc).S
```

The syntax rule for `include` is defined as

```
include module-expr
```

and `moduule-expr` does not allow a dot after parentheses. I suspect it's an extension. Can someone point it out what does this include mean and which rule does it relate to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax refers to the inclusion of the signature `S` found at

```
module SpecificWarning = Warning (Loc)
include SpecificWarning.S
```

In this case the syntax allows for `SpecificWarning` to be constructed anonymously

```
include (Warning(Loc)).S
```

The syntactic rule is linked under [the rule for `module-type`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/modtypes.html#module-type) seeing that it allows for valid [`modtype-path` segments](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/names.html#modtype-path) which allows for `extended-module-name`s (e.g. module names possibly augmented by parenthetical functor application syntax) followed by a `.` and then a identifier acting as a `modtype-name` from within the anonymous module created via the functor application.

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to the modules, for which it is indeed is not allowed. But the example is about signatures, aka module types. Here is the motivating demo:

```
       OCaml version 4.01.0

# module type S = sig type t end;;
module type S = sig type t end
# module Make(T : S) = struct
  module type S = sig
      type t = T.t list
    end 
end;;
        module Make :
  functor (T : S) -> sig module type S = sig type t = T.t list end end
# module type Example = sig
            include Make(String).S
          end;;
    module type Example = sig type t = String.t list end
#
```